# C++ can i declare on reference member?

Tags: c++

In the h file i declare:

```
static IDataSynchronization& sync_data_;
```

But in the cpp , I have compilation error for sync_data_ :

```
IDataSynchronization& MasterSlaveSynchronize::sync_data_;
```

Error is :

```
MasterSlaveSynchronize::sync_data_ declared as reference but not initialized
```

I can , but dont want to declare is as a pointer and i want to learn what is the problem here and if there is a way to bypass this.

I cannot initialize at declaration , because this is kind of callback that will pass at setup (no constructor , static setup).

Thank you

Comment: A reference has to be initialized at the time of creation.

Comment: **but not initialized** You must set this reference to some variable. By `IDataSynchronization& MasterSlaveSynchronize::sync_data_ = XXX;`

Comment: I can setup it only on runrime, so using reference cannot help to callback impl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you need to initialize it:

```
IDataSynchronization& MasterSlaveSynchronize::sync_data_ = something;
```

Answer (score 1):

References must be initialized in the declaration. If as it seems from your comments you cannot do that, then you will have to resort to pointers. There is no third option there.

Comment: Stupid question - why in the h file it dosnt complain , and the compilation error is in the cpp ?

Comment: Because they must be initialized in the definition, not declaration as David says. And since the definition is not in header, it is not complaining in .h.

Comment: But the essential part of David's message is that you'll have to use pointers if you don't know what you're referencing at the time of initialization.

Comment: I remove the definition from the cpp and now it compiled ok , the setup and the execute.

Comment: @user1495181: Removing the definition will make it compile (and link) until you actually *use* the member in the program. At that point it will fail to link complaining that the static member has not been defined (or missing symbol or something alike, depending on your compiler)